# Creating hover overs in Dreamweaver

Tags: jquery, css, html, dreamweaver

I have been looking for a hover over tutorial which splits the page in half. You can view two brief diagrams below:

[image] [image]

Essentailly, when the user hovers over any of those 3 buttons, I want it to display another list of buttons below by opening up a part of the page under the buttons or as I called it, splitting it.

I have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to this detail of HTML. I am using Dreamweaver CS6 if that helps at all (if there is a feature that allows what i'm doing).

Comment: Without posting any code were not going to be of much help but there are more than enough tutorials out there on this from a basic google search https://www.google.com/search?q=basic+hover+over+dreamweaver&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=basic+nav+hover+over+dreamweaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 ways : experiment to see which one you need.

FROM SIDE MENU :

Just a multi-level menu :
-Insert/Layout/Spry Menu Bars

Each tab show different content in the box :
-Insert/Layout/Spry Tabbed Panels

FROM TOP MENU :

-Insert/Spry/Menu Bars

-Insert/Spry/Spry Tabbed Panels

These Spry are easy to learn.
Good luck.

(i hope i translated correctly, my DW is in not in english)